# Parse HTML table for specific content in one column and print resulting table to file with python

Tags: python, html

I have a file test_input.htm with a table:

```
    <table>
          <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th>Acronym</th>
                    <th>Full Term</th>
                    <th>Definition</th>
                    <th>Product </th>
                </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>a1</td>
                    <td>term</td>
                    <td>
                        <p>texttext.</p>
                        <p>Source: PRISMA-GLO</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>PRISMA</p>
                        <p>SDDS-NG</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a2</td>
                    <td>term</td>
                    <td>
                        <p>texttext.</p>
                        <p>Source: PRISMA-GLO</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>PRISMA</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a3</td>
                    <td>term</td>
                    <td>
                        <p>texttext.</p>
                        <p>Source: PRISMA-GLO</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>SDDS-NG</p>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>a4</td>
                    <td>term</td>
                    <td>
                        <p>texttext.</p>
                        <p>Source: SD-GLO</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>SDDS-NG</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>         
           </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like to write only table rows to file test_output.htm that contain the keyword PRISMA in column 4 (Product).

The follwing script gives me all table rows that contain the keyword PRISMA in any of the 4 columns:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_input = open('test_input.htm')
results = BeautifulSoup(file_input.read(), 'html.parser')
inhalte = results.find_all('tr')


with open('test_output.htm', 'a') as f:
    data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in inhalte]]
    for line in inhalte: #if you see a line in the table
        if line.get_text().find('PRISMA') > -1 : #and you find the specific string
                f.write("%s\n" % str(line))
```

I really tried hard but could not figure out how to restict the search to column 4.
The following did not work:

```
data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll('td')[4]] for tr in inhalte]  

I would really appreciate if someone could help me find the solution.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select more specific to get the elements you expect - For example use `css selectors` to achieve your task. Following line will only select tr from table thats fourth td contains PRISMA:

```
soup.select('table tr:has(td:nth-of-type(4):-soup-contains("PRISMA"))')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_input = open('test_input.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_input.read(), 'html.parser')

with open('test_output.htm', 'a') as f:
    for line in soup.select('table tr:has(td:nth-of-type(4):-soup-contains("PRISMA"))'):
        f.write("%s\n" % str(line))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick answer. I am very happy with the solution.